# Most efficient way to compare multiple arrays based on a fixed element and copy the largest one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've four arrays of length 18 (`k1`,`k2`,`k3`&`k4`). I want to compare the last element of each array & copy the contents of the array with the largest final element.

Currently, this is how I'm doing it:

```
if (this.k4[17]>=this.k1[17] && this.k4[17]>=this.k2[17] && this.k4[17]>=this.k3[17])
            m = this.k4.filter(() => true);
        else if(this.k1[17]>=this.k4[17] && this.k1[17]>=this.k2[17] && this.k1[17]>=this.k3[17])
            m = this.k1.filter(() => true);
        else if(this.k2[17]>=this.k4[17] && this.k2[17]>=this.k1[17] && this.k2[17]>=this.k3[17])
            m = this.k2.filter(() => true);
        else
            m = this.k3.filter(() => true);
```

But this isn't scalable incase I added more arrays in the future.

Here is another method:

```
var maxlast = [this.k1[17],this.k2[17],this.k3[17],this.k4[17]];
var max = maxlast.reduce(function(a,b){return Math.max(a, b)}, -Infinity);
var pos = maxlast.indexOf(max)+1;
m = eval("this.k"+pos+".filter(() => true);");
```

I've heard eval() is a major security risk, is there an alternative approach?

Comment: Please see if this helps: `const arrayOfArrays = [ k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6 ]; const findLargestLast = (arrOuter = arrayOfArrays) => (arrOuter.reduce((fin, arr) => (arr.slice(-1) > fin.tot ? ({ tot: arr.slice(-1), foundArr: [...arr]}) : fin), {tot: -Infinity, foundArr: []})?.foundArr);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sort and just return the first element of `descending sorted list`

```
const arr = [this.k1, this.k2, this.k3, this.k4]
// sort desc
const arrayHasMaxLastElement = arr.sort((a, b) => b[b.length - 1] - a[a.length - 1])[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get max item with `reduce`

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];

const result = arr.reduce((max, item) => max.at(-1) > item.at(-1) ? max : item);

console.log(...result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```